# i5-3210M to an intel i7-3610QM?

Tags: cpu, upgrade, intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5

If i want to upgrade my processor in my laptop from a i5-3210M to an i7-3610QM what else, if anything would i need to change? They both have the same sockets, I"m thinking i might need to upgrade the fan, but is this necessary?

Comment: There's no way we can know without knowing what laptop you have. But most likely, nothing else. You're going from a 25W CPU to a 35W CPU, that's not a huge jump. If the cooling is inadequate, it just will mean you won't get all the performance you might get otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The i5-3210M is 35W, the i7-3610QM is 45W. The laptop I have is an ACER Aspire V3-571G. If i did need to upgrade the cooling, what would that involve?

Comment: @Christy you're pretty much S.O.L. if you need to change the cooling.  The best you can do is use an aftermarket thermal compound in hopes of improving the efficiency of your existing cooling setup, but aside from custom-fabricating your own heatsinks, what you have is what you're going to stay with.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that you have experience taking apart laptops.

First, the socket. It's the same socket on both CPUs (rPGA988B), but make sure your CPU isn't soldered on (it appears that the socket is a pin-socket, but it may vary between OEMs)

Second, the cooling. What are your (1-hour+) load temperatures right now? If they're below 80, then there should be just enough headroom for your 40% increase in heat. If they're hitting 80+, I'd recommend not upgrading, unless there a version of your laptop with a higher-power processor. If the higher-power version has the same heatsink, then you're fine; if it has a bigger heatsink, get the bigger heatsink as well.

For information on heatsink sizes, check Ebay / similar - that's how I upgraded my own laptop heatsink.

Comment: nice info....+1